# Paren child relationship in object model

Tags: model, domain-driven-design, object-model

When you creating domain model does you referencing parent in child class?
Does child objects knows who is their parent?

```
class Parent
{
    public string Id {get;set;}
    public ChildList IList<Child> {get;set;}     
}
class Child 
{
    public string Id {get; set;}
    public string Name {get;set}
    public Parent Father {get; set;} // reference or not parent?
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you need in the end, i.e. what you want to do with the model.

The advantage of having references in both direction is, the better navigability, which may not be necessary.

The disadvantage of having references in both directions is, higher maintenance efforts, at least if you code those classes yourself, instead of generating them.

Having the dependency in only one direction can make sense i certain use cases. E.g. you only know the parent and want to crawl all children or vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

Use the YAGNI principle - do the reference one way, until you see you need it in both.